# How to optimize the return value of rvalue parameter to avoid copy

Tags: c++

I am writing a network module, using the envelope model, The following is a sent function, the function parameter uses rvalue reference：

```cpp
Envelope NatsTransport::Send(Envelope&& envelope)
{
    // do somthing...

    if (!natsConnection->Send(envelope.GetContent(), envelope.Length()))
    {
        return envelope.With<SentFaildStamp>("envelope send faild");
    }

    return envelope; // called the envelope's copy constructor
    // return std::move(envelope); // called the envelope's copy constructor
}
```

```cpp
template <class TStamp, typename... Args>
Envelope With(Args&&... args) const 
{
     // When the With method is called, the copy constructor of the
     // envelope is called. This is in line with the design expectations,
     // because adding stamps to the envelope will not modify the old envelope.
     return With(std::make_shared<TStamp>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

But I found it call envelope's copy constructor when it returned.

Is there a way to avoid the call of the copy constructor and use move semantics?

I used the debug mode for breakpoint tracking and found the call of the copy constructor.

---

**NOTE:** I tried to implement the move constructor, but it doesn’t seem to work when returning a value.

```cpp
class Envelope final 
{
public:
    Envelope::Envelope(const Envelope& other) 
    {
        offset_ = other.offset_;
        length_ = other.length_;
        content_ = other.content_;
        stamps_ = other.stamps_;
    }
   
    Envelope(Envelope&& other)
    {
        offset_ = other.offset_;
        length_ = other.length_;
        content_ = std::move(other.content_);
        stamps_ = std::move(other.stamps_);
    }

    Envelope& operator=(const Envelope& other) noexcept
    {
       if (this == &other)
       {
           return *this;
       }

       offset_ = other.offset_;
       length_ = other.length_;
       content_ = other.content_;
       stamps_ = other.stamps_;

       return *this;
    }

    Envelope& operator=(Envelope&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this == &other)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        offset_ = other.offset_;
        length_ = other.length_;
        content_ = std::move(other.content_);
        stamps_ = std::move(other.stamps_);

        return *this;
    }

private:
    size_t offset_ = 0;
    size_t length_ = -1;
    std::shared_ptr<const void> content_ = nullptr;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StampInterface>>> stamps_;
}
```

Comment: `const Envelope&&` This makes no sense. You almost never want a const rvalue reference. Drop the const.

Comment: There is *never* a good reason to create a `const` r-value reference.

Comment: Does envelope have a move constructor? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried to implement the move constructor, but it doesn’t seem to work when returning a value.

Comment: Your example doesn't have a copy constructor? Please post a [mre] of the exact code you're using

Comment: I've tried to compile. In the case of `return std::move(envelope);` the move constructor is called. Please provide more details.

Comment: I want to say an awful thing - do not optimize return value using std::move.
Let compiler make return-value optimization. Some arguments you can find here, Chapter 5.3. www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PGCMGDQ/

Comment: For your copy/move constructor/assignment, default implementation is correct, so a simple `= default;` do the job.

Comment: We don't need return `std::move` on local variable, but OP uses reference, so need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving const objects (as in your original post) selects regular copy constructor over move constructor.

You would need `Envelope(const Envelope&&)` which has actually really few usage.

When argument is not const

`return std::move(envelope)` should call move constructor (if available).

`return envelope` call copy constructor. There are cases where move is called, if `envelope` is a local variable, but it is not your case (it is a (rvalue-)reference here).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, when I remove the const, the move constructor is called correctly

Comment: But I am more curious, why is c++ designed this way, and why it will lead to the result of calling different constructors.

Comment: Overload resolution select the best match between the viable overload. const object doesn't bind to non-const (rvalue) reference, so the only viable candidate is the copy constructor.